# JS FetchAPI Get Request add raw body data

Tags: javascript, postman, fetch-api

I have a GET request setup in Postman with raw body data as below and it works. I can get data from the server
[image]

But my Js fetch api I'm not sure how to add request body data to it.
Here is my GET request config

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://example.net:/app/v1/cmp/displacer/url", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

But it returns error

```
error TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

The server only accept GET request for that URL.
I tried to googled but no luck.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) and [Swagger TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48749252)

Answer (score 2):

Sending a BODY (a.k.a. payload) in a GET request is [unsupported by fetch](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/551) because [its behavior is undefined in HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) and a lot of other systems don't support it or handle it in unexpected ways. If you need to send a BODY along, you should probably be using a different method than GET; If you need to send parameters with your GET request, you can try sending a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).